# Acumatica, generic inquiry related to budgets

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica, I'm trying to build a generic inquiry related to budgets.  What table has the budget per month data?

I have gathered the YTD information from the 'GL Budget Line' table.  But I need further information.

Please help.  Brandon

Answer (score 2):

The amounts allocated for each particular period may be found in the `GLBudgetLineDetail` table (and through the corresponding DAC). Each record in this table presents data for a particular *Account, Subaccount and Financial Period*.

The columns that may be of particular interest for you are `Amount` and `ReleasedAmount`. The first one stores the editable budget amount - that is actually what user edits through the *Budgets* screen. The second reflects the released amount of budget for the period, account and sub - this field is populated with the value of `Amount` during the budget release process.